# How do I get a cloned Django project running?

Tags: python, django, github, web, pip

When I do 'pip install -r requirements.txt', I get this message: python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully[image: Full error message]

I tried python 'python3 -m pip install -U setuptools' but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove psycopg2 from requirements.txt then use
'psycopg2-binary'

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```